# How to return parent id of a child document in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a parent-child relationship in Elastic Search.  When I do a search on the child documents, I also want to get for each child the id of the parent.

I saw that you can use _parent in filtering, but can I also use it in the "fields" array that I want to return ?

Example of my query:

```
{
  //Fields to return
  "fields":[
    "_parent.id",     >> Does not work
    "_parent.title",  >> Does not work
    "commentText"
  ], 


  //Query (Filtered query)
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      //Filter
      "filter":{
        "and":[        
          {
            "type":{ "value": "comment" }
          }
        ]   
      },
      //Query
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "xxx",
          "type": "best_fields",
          "fields": [
            "commentText"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think _parent only stores the parent id. Try something like this:

```
"fields":[
    "_parent",     
    "commentText"
  ]
```

Comment: This works indeed.  Was hoping to be able to get also other fields, but I can start with the parent Id.  Thx.